# How to make a list with Table View Cells with user input from another view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm making an iOS app with Swift that has two scenes. One asks for user input and that is saved in an array. I'm trying to make a list with table view cells in the other scene, and that list includes the user input that is saved when the user clicks on the save button.

tried creating a sharedData class in a separate file, tried this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as! goalViewController
        svc.toPass = textInput
    }
}
```

(both from other stackoverflow questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the array into the NSUserDefaults then recall the objects you saved in the NSUserDefaults in the new view.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Using `Delegate` is one of the preferred way

**Example:**

```
protocol PExposeArrayDelegate: class
{
   func getArrayOfItems(array: String)
}


class CustomArray
{

// delegate property to expose array to the view-controller
    internal weak var delegateForTimeLineCell: PExposeArrayDelegate?


internal func createArray()
{
    let arr = ["Vivek","India","Audi"]

     delegateForTimeLineCell.getArrayOfItems(array: arr)
}

}
```

**Now in the class where you want to access the array, do the following:**

**-** Conform to `protocol` (Delegate) defined above

**-** Assign `self` to the `delegate`

**-** Implement the `delegate method` and then access the array from inside it.

[Check the example here](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/)